# Simple 24VAC solenoid controller for Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am a bit new in making circuits, but I am truly stuck.

I need to control a 24VAC irrigation valve from an Arduino type environment. I have seen several post but I just don't get it. The only power supply I have is the 24VAC so it would have to power the 5V DC Arduino too (that I have been able to manage).
Any ideas of links? With a simple diagram and a good explanation?

Comment: Ideas for what?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way: power the Arduino with a separate 5V USB wall wart. Then, use an Arduino relay shield for the 24VAC valves. Finally, use the 24VAC only for the valves.

You can also find 24VAC to USB 5V - search for exactly that and lots of choices come up.

The reason I recommend the USB plug approach is that the losses will be less than using the 9V-ish barrel plug. But you can can do that, too, if that's your preference.